# Can't install extensions per schema as it claims that it exists in there (it doesn't). How to force it any further?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use dblink, I have thousands of schemas.

I have tried to install dblink extension using:

```
create extension dblink schema exampleschema;
```

Of course I am getting this error:

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [42710]: ERROR: extension "dblink" already exists
```

This is not true as I cannot use dblink for specific schema (I am accessing it  through the app that I am the dev) as it cannot find it.

Only way to make dblink work is to use set search to a schema were extensions I've managed to install.

1. I've tried to set search path to a schema where extension is missing
2. Tried to use above query
3. Tried to set connection active to selected schema

Can't figure out what I would be able to use...

Extension was only created for public and schema1, however everytime I try to install extension to any other schema I will get information that extension is missing (extensions is not found when using query (when set search path to proper schema) or checking in system info / extensions).

How can I force postgresql to install extension in specific schema ? Is there any other query as obviously above query doesn't work (extensions doesn't exist in exampleschema)

Comment: Run `\dx dblink` in `psql` and add the result to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extension is not installed *per schema*, but *per database*.

> Extension was only created for public and schema1

You are misunderstanding how an extension is installed.

An extension is installed **in** one (and only one) schema, which means that all functions that the extension provides are created **in that schema**.  So if you installed the dblink extension in the schema `dblink_schema` all dblink functions are stored there.

To make that extension available to users that have a different search_path, you need to change that user's search_path to include the schema where the extension is installed  in (not to the schema where it's missing), e.g.:

```
alter user app_user
  set search_path = public,dblink_schema;
```

Comment: So what if I have > 100 schemas, different extensions and big queries that are using different search_path (pretty normal scenario for any normal application)

Comment: @Mike: I typically install all extensions into a single schema (e.g. `extensions`) then I only need to add a single schema to the search_path of all users. Or put everything global (=used by all users) into `public` which is part of the default search_path.

Comment: Thanks, not bad idea. I will take a look into that.